# Differences in width between page in localhost and server

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made ​​this simple page with standard bootstrap3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="immagini/logo.ico">

<title>Company</title>

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" /> 

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<div class="container logo"><img src="immagini/logo.png"></div>

<div class="container">

 <!-- navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo WEB_ROOT; ?>">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
   </div>
  </div> <!-- /container -->

  <div class="container">

  </div>

 <div class="container">    

  <footer>
     <small>Company 2013</small>

  </footer>  

</div>


 <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

The page is fine, but do not understand why in localhost (WAMP) the width of the layout appears as I want

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
   }
```

The exact same page that is loaded on the server (LAMP) appears with a tighter layout

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
 .container {
  max-width: 970px;
   }
```

Why???  I found this problem only with V3 version

Comment: You are overriding `bootstrap.css` with `docs.css` which it is using media queries, so you're creating an "adaptable website layout" to the screen or resolution that the OS are using

Comment: I have the same issue with v2.2:

   <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css">